# Can't install elementary os 6 on a 4k native ssd

Tags: system-installation, hardware, release-odin, ssd

The installer assume sector size is 512 bytes, so EFI system partition is 300 MB / 4 and it won't let me proceed with the install.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Same thing happening in MacBook Pro 15 (2017) GParted is showing correctly the sizes, not the installer.